# Is it possible to have a List<string> as a property on an active record class

Tags: c#, collections, castle-activerecord

Is it possible to have a HasMany relationship of a basic type such as String, on an ActiveRecord class, without the need for creating another entity such as (TodoListItem) to hold the value.

```
[ActiveRecord]
public class TodoList
{

  [PrimaryKey]
  public int Id
  {
    get { return _id; }
    set { _id = value; }
  }

  [HasMany(typeof(string)]
  public IList<string> Items
  {
    get { return _items; }
    set { _items= value; }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. You can map a one-to-many relation to a built-in or simple type (value type or string) rather than a persisted type.

You'll need to specify the `ColumnKey`, `Table` and `Element` params in the `HasMany` attribute declaration to get it to wire up properly. You have to have a surrogate key column so the AR can handle updates and cascades, and then `Element` tells AR which column in the table holds the simple value it will use to make the list.

```
[HasMany(typeof(string), Table="ToDoList_Items", 
         ColumnKey = "ListItemID", Element = "Item")]
public IList<string> Items { get; set; }
```

(or something similar - I haven't got a compiler handy on this box to check it; but per the API docs it ought to work.)

Speaking of which, if you haven't already had a look, http://api.castleproject.org is kinda indispensible for any work with the Castle stack.

Answer (score -1):

In ActiveRecord, your types map to a record in a table (by default).  It seems like you are confusing how this type should map to your table.

The MyClass type should have a definition something like this (excluding the PK settings):

```
[ActiveRecord(Table = "MyTable")]
public class MyClass : ActiveRecordBase<MyClass>
{
    [Property]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public int MyClassId { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public string ListItem { get; set; }
}
```

Then, to load the list:

```
public void LoadMyClasses()
{
    MyClass[] results = MyClass.FindAll();
}
```

I'd suggest you spend some time with the [ActiveRecord documentation](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/index.html) (or [tutorial](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/gettingstarted/index.html)) as that should also help clear up any confusion.

Comment: I am really after a list of strings as a property on an active record class, I have removed some of the detail to highlight what I am really after. thanks